# DOWS meaning in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am reading a book which shows this example

```
SELECT wait_type ,
SUM(wait_time_ms / 1000) AS [wait_time_s]
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats DOWS
WHERE wait_type NOT IN ( 'SLEEP_TASK', 'BROKER_TASK_STOP',
'SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH', 'CLR_AUTO_EVENT',
'CLR_MANUAL_EVENT', 'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP' )
GROUP BY wait_type
ORDER BY SUM(wait_time_ms) DESC
```

I want to know the exact role(meaning) of a keyword DOWS next to FROM statement. I tried to search but nothing helpful was found.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: as Paul white said its an alias. You can alias your table any way you want but here I think the author of this code used this. sys.`d`m_`o`s_`w`ait_`s`tats ==>DOWS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the `table_alias` as shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the `FROM` clause.

> ```
> [ FROM {  } [ ,...n ] ]   
>  ::=   
> {  
>     table_or_view_name [ [ AS ] table_alias ]   
>         [  ]   
>         [ WITH (  [ [ , ]...n ] ) ]   
>     | rowset_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ]   
>         [ ( bulk_column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]   
>     | user_defined_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
>     | OPENXML    
>     | derived_table [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]   
>     |    
>     |    
>     |   
>     | @variable [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
>     | @variable.function_call ( expression [ ,...n ] )   
>         [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ (column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]  
>     | FOR SYSTEM_TIME    
> }
> ```

It would be clearer if the code author had chosen to use the optional `AS` keyword, and to use the alias elsewhere in the query:

```
SELECT 
    DOWS.wait_type,
    SUM(DOWS.wait_time_ms / 1000) AS [wait_time_s]
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats AS DOWS
WHERE 
    DOWS.wait_type NOT IN 
    ( 
        'SLEEP_TASK', 'BROKER_TASK_STOP',
        'SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH', 'CLR_AUTO_EVENT',
        'CLR_MANUAL_EVENT', 'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP' 
    )
GROUP BY 
    DOWS.wait_type
ORDER BY 
    SUM(DOWS.wait_time_ms) DESC;
```